# How to create FileUpload

Tags: discord-jda

I'm currently trying to send an image through JDA but can't get it to work. The only thing I can find on Google is the addFile (java.io.File) method, which is no longer available in the most recent version of JDA. I am currently struggling to find a solution using the addFiles() method.

This is my current attempt.

```
byte[] buffer = ((DataBufferByte)(img).getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
FileUpload upload = new FileUpload(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
c.sendMessage("Image:").addFiles(upload).complete();
```

I am getting this error message in my IDE, but I don't know what to make of it.
[image: my error]

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the factory method [FileUpload.fromData](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/utils/FileUpload.html#fromData(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String)):

```java
FileUpload upload = FileUpload.fromData(buffer, "image.png");
```

Make sure you properly encode the image to something like `JPG` or `PNG`, otherwise this will not work.